# How to set up .httaccess to subfolder

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have these structure on my FTP:

- one presentation (without .htaccess)

  - second presentation (with .htaccess) - named "sec_pres"
  - third pres. (with .htaccess) - named - "third_pres"

How I should set to `.htaccess` in **second presentation** for the right run? This is my set up of `.htaccess` on localhost and works me pretty well:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(images|css)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/robots.txt$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?gotcha=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried to to edit `htaccess` for the second presentation:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/sec_pres/(images|css)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/sec_pres/robots.txt$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/sec_pres/favicon.ico$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?gotcha=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But with the set up above I got in the browser (**web.com/sec_pres/**) displayed the first presentation without a CSS and images...
Could anyone help me the right way of set up?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the first presentation located?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even close to an expert on this subject, but i'll give it a try

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?gotcha=$1 [L,QSA]

Shouldnt you use $2?